# Why isn't webpack retaining console.log statements?

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules, code-splitting

I'm doing my first tests with webpack and experimenting with code splitting, and I simply wanted to log from my index.js file. It gets compiled, but it doesn't log nothing, both in development or in production mode. Files are compiled and loaded. Very strange. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong... Could you please point me in the right direction?

```
// index.js
import _ from 'lodash';
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import { Fancybox, Carousel, Panzoom } from "@fancyapps/ui";

function log(){
  console.log('from index');
  console.log(Swiper);
  console.log(Fancybox, Carousel, Panzoom);
  console.log(_);
}

log();
```

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //mode: 'development',
  mode: 'production',
  watch: true,
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    //page_2: './src/page-2.js'
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },

  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        visuals: {
          name: 'visuals',
          chunks: 'all',
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](swiper|@fancyapps\/ui|dom7|ssr-window)[\\/]/
        },
        lowdash: {
          name: 'lowdash',
          chunks: 'all',
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]lodash[\\/]/
        }
      },
    }
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: { presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] }
        }
      } // babel
    ] // rules
  } // module
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would the as part of the optimization that webpack does, it cleans out your `console.logs`.

You could try adding

```js
optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
};
```

and see if that helps. Although I'm surprised it's doing it in dev mode as well.

Comment: Yes in dev too, that's the reason why I didn't try minimize false. But in fact, I see console.log, at least in dev, it gets written inside the initial eval function. Still, it doesn't show on browser console.

Comment: I tried with minimize false but didn't work. I just found out it must be lodash. If I comment out lodash import, it will work. But ok, I guess lodash is causing some errors: when are they logged then? How can I debug or at least understand the reason why lodash is causing issues?

Comment: Ok, I've found the problem, and it was trivial: I didn't load lodash (lowdash.js). I was only loading visuals.js and index.js. But anyway, still, why didn't I get any warning/errors in console then? It was simply blank.